# Bind RichTextBox without typing a lot of useless code or add HyperLinks to strings?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I had a class with `<toolkit:ExpanderView>`-elements. Those are bound to a ViewModel and need to stay bound, because I'm already using a lot of checks like "Which VM-element is expanded and which not", etc.

The text inside of that expanded part was read from localized Strings (AppResources.resx) and added inside of the VM. But now I have to add hyperlinks to that text.

My idea was to throw away the localized strings for a while and create RichTextBoxes inside of the ViewModel. Instead of binding strings to the expanded part I would bind the RichTextBoxes.

But all methods I find suck. e.g.:

```
StackPanel tempGrid = new StackPanel();
StackPanel tempGrid = new StackPanel();
RichTextBox tempRtb = new RichTextBox();
Paragraph tempPara = new Paragraph();

Run tempRun = new Run();
Hyperlink tempHLink = new Hyperlink();
tempHLink.Click += Hyperlink_Click;

tempRun.Text = "line 1\nline 2\nline 3";
tempPara.Inlines.Add(tempRun);
tempRun.Text = "\nTel.:       ";
tempPara.Inlines.Add(tempRun);
tempHLink.Inlines.Add("+01800 000 000 000");
tempPara.Inlines.Add(tempHLink);
tempRun.Text = "\nE-Mail: ";
tempPara.Inlines.Add(tempRun);
tempHLink.Inlines.Add("e-mail@email.com");
tempPara.Inlines.Add(tempHLink);
```

But it fails already when I reuse `tempRun`. Should I add thousands of new variables? ôo
Also the in the spec ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 ) it says that something like

```
Run run = new Run("string");
```

should work. But it doesn't with WP8 and turns to

```
Run run = new Run();
run.text = "string";
```

So everything becomes WAY longer... :(

Edit:

Yes, forgot to ask the actual question: Is there a faster way to fill a richtextbox or paragraph with lots of `Run` or `Hyperlink`-elements?
And how do I bind it in my xaml?
I need something like:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <RichTextBox Content="{Binding MyModelViewParagraph}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

to bind my paragraph from the ViewModel to the xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, googling further lead me to this:

ViewModel:

```
StackPanel tempStack = new StackPanel();
RichTextBox tempRtb = new RichTextBox();
Paragraph tempPara = new Paragraph();

//tempHLink.Click += Hyperlink_Click;

tempPara.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "text 1\ntext 2\n text 3" });
tempPara.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "\nTel.:       " });
//tempInline.Add(new Hyperlink { new InlineCollection {  =  } }) // "+000 (0) 00 00 00-0"
tempPara.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "\nE-Mail: " });
//tempInline.Add(new Hyperlink { new InlineCollection {  =  } }) // e-mail@email.com

tempRtb.Blocks.Add(tempPara);
tempStack.Children.Add(tempRtb);
```

Still need to find out how exactly I give Text and Click-Event to every HyperLink but that'll be managable I guess..

xaml:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

That binds my Stackpanel so I can add as many elements as I need.

Sorry for answering it by myself. Sometimes you seem to be stuck and it's better to ask then lose 2-3 more days on something that might be simple.. And sometimes asking the question leads you to a solution. In my case it was just mroe stupid googling and reading the MS-specification xD

Edit:
If someone ants to know the whole solutionf ro the Hyperlinks as well - I found out :)

```
tempPara.Inlines.Add(CreateHyperlinkWithContent("+00 (00) 00 00 00-0"));
```

With the method:

```
private Hyperlink CreateHyperlinkWithContent(string content)
{
    Hyperlink tempHyperLink = new Hyperlink();
    tempHyperLink.Inlines.Add(content);
    tempHyperLink.Click += Hyperlink_Click;
    tempHyperLink.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0x33, 0x66, 0x99));
    tempHyperLink.MouseOverForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0x33, 0x66, 0x99));
    return tempHyperLink;
}
```

This is the shortest way I could find to add Text and Links in a single Line everytime ;)